# How to iterate over a HashMap starting from a particular key value in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

Is there a way to start iteration in HashMap from a particular key?

Suppose my map is :

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put(1,"A");
map.put(2,"B");
map.put(3,"B");
map.put(4,"B");
map.put(5,"F");
map.put(6,"Z");
```

And I want the iteration to start from key `2`.

The regular iteration involves :

```
public static void printMap(Map map) {
    Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        }
}
```

But how to start the iteration from a particular key?

Comment: You cannot do that with a HashMap as the iteration order is undefined. You want a TreeMap (or looking at your indexes, maybe just an array or a List).

Comment: Also, in your example you're defining `map` as a [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). It's best to not do that (see link). Try `Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>()` instead. :)

Comment: Are you using the key (1, 2, 3,...) from the map as some kind of index? Or is it only  for the example?

Comment: A HashMap doesn't sort ts data in a particular order. Your question is invalid read the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html ? Use a TreeMap as suggested...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding of what a `HashMap` is.  In particular, if you started at the key `2` and iterated the remaining entries, there is *no guarantee* that you would get entries with keys `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` and `6` ... in that order, or in any order.

The order of iteration for a `HashMap` is undefined, and in most cases unpredictable.

However ... if you used a `LinkedHashMap` or a `TreeMap` and iterated the entries then you would get them in a defined order:

- a `LinkedHashMap` would (typically) give the entries in insertion order
- a `TreeMap` would give the entries in comparison order of the keys.

If you use a `LinkedHashMap`, the way to get all entries starting from a given key (in insertion order) is to iterate from the start until you get to the key you want.  For example:

```
public static void printMapFrom(LinkedHashMap<K, V> map, K from) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Map<K, V>.Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (!found && !from.equals(entry.getKey())) {
            continue;
        }
        found = true;
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

If you use a `TreeMap`, the way to do it is to use `tailMap(key)` to get the submap of entries from the key to the end.  Then you iterate the submap.

```
public static void printMapFrom(SortedMap<K, V> map, K from) {
    for (Map<K, V>.Entry entry : map.tailMap(from).entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

If you actually don't care that the order of keys in a `HashMap` is indeterminate, then you can use the `LinkedHashMap` version above with a plain `HashMap` or a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Hey, I know this is from a while ago, but I'm trying to loop through a map with a specific key and the value that's mapped is also another key and so on and so on. Is there a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: That is nothing to do with this Q&A.  Please 1) search the existing Questions for something like your problem, 2) if you cannot find one ask a new one.

Answer (score -1):

first define your `map Map<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();`
And then you can use like it

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry: map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getKey() == 1){
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() +" : "+ entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: thanks for updated me i have changed the HashMap to linkedHashMap

Comment: it will preserved the insertion order

Comment: Still doesn't work in general.  What happens if there is more than one key to be skipped over?